# Не работают fn на ноутбуке asus k55vm

Tags: linux, kernel

Вся беда в том что на ядре 3.13 generic все пашет, как только обновляюсь на ядро версии повыше, то fn не работают и появляется ошибка error pch transcoder при загрузке системы. Так же слетает регулятор громкости, при включении он постоянно на 100проц.

Вот еще и моник тухнет (  подсветка ) после пару минут работы.

Comment: у меня рабочий ноут k55v. Ошибка pch transcoder при загрузке системы при загрузке системы есть, но никак не мешает. Функциональные кнопки работают как ожидается (громкость, яркость, плеер, калькулятор). Монитор не тухнет. ядро - 3.19.5-200.fc21.x86_64, Fedora 21.

Какой дистрибутив используете, ядро с репозитория или самосборное?

Comment: Ядро 4.0 с репозитория, дист linux mint 17

Comment: попробуйте сделать так - скачайте лайв дистрибутив федоры/убунты (хотя убунту лучше не брать - минт - это таже убунта, только с своими глюками, которые называют улучшениями) и потестить. Если бага уйдет - просто смените дистр:)

Comment: Смена дистра думаю для меня не самое подходящее в настоящее время

Answer (score 1):

> на ядре 3.13 generic все пашет, как только обновляюсь на ядро версии повыше

самое логичное **в данной ситуации** решение: не обновлять программу *linux*.

Comment: Я вот пытался сменить дистр на федору новую и тоже самое. Не знаю что за хрень.

Comment: у меня ноут asus k54c и стоит три разные версии Linux , Ubuntu 15.04, RedHut, Fedora и везде все клавиши работают , только в федоре самопроизвольно включается NumLock и из за того клавиши меняются и когда горит Num не горит индикатор приходится догадываться что включено